# Startup guide for ektron

Tags: content-management-system, ektron

What is the best way to start with ektron? Any ebook reference and video links for novice 
developer.

I want to teach anatomy of ektron cms.

Many thanks,
Jigar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the **webinars** I would start off with, in the following order:

1. *Getting Started: Developing with Ektron* - this webinar is super basic, but it’s well worth going through for Ektron newbies. Covers the different installers, installation, adding content, and getting the content on the website using either Server Controls or the API. http://www.ektron.com/Webinars/Details/Getting-Started--Developing-with-Ektron/
2. *The Ektron Framework API and Microsoft LINQ* – this covers the new Framework API that was introduced in v8.5. The webinar covers the Framework APIs design goals, sample source, etc.
   http://ektron.com/Resources/Webinars/Framework-API/
3. *Ektron Content Types* - ContentTypes are .NET classes that are mapped to Ektron Smart Forms. SmartForms are simply structured content items (e.g. Book, Contact, Employee, etc).
   http://ektron.com/Resources/Webinars/Ektron-Content-Types/
4. *Search Framework API* - The Search architecture can be used to deliver content and go beyond simple site search. This webinar provides an introduction to the Search architecture as well as an overview of the Search Framework API. http://www.ektron.com/Webinars/Details/Ektron-8-5-and-the-Search-Framework-API/
5. *Building an Extensible and Maintainable Website on Ektron* - This webinar discusses what it takes to build an extensible and maintainable web application, covering the benefits of building a properly layered website and walking you through the process of building a functional website. http://www.ektron.com/Webinars/Details/Building-an-Extensible-and-Maintainable-Website-on-Ektron---Part-1/

The **documentation** and **books** I recommend

- http://documentation.ektron.com/
- http://reference.ektron.com/
- [Ektron Developers Guide, published by WROX Press](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470885696)

Ektron has a **training** department that offers the following courses:

- Advanced Developer Training (*this is a new training*)
- Intro Developer Training (*this was revamped for the v8.5 release*)
- Admin Training
- Custom Training

Ektron has an active **developer forum**

- http://developer.ektron.com/

Comment: Thanks, a lot of the links might be outdated based on the fact that I tried one and it doesn't exist anymore. Could you update please?

Comment: Hi David, I updated the links in the post. Should be all set now.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the following, in order of usefulness-

- [Ektron Webinars](http://www.ektron.com/Resources/Webinars/)
- Starter/demo sites, particularly the developer demo
- [Code Exchange site](http://dev.ektron.com/exchange/), you can download and look at other's code snippets.
- [Ektron forums](http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx), particularly the [developer forum](http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=topics&f=88)

Comment: Thanks for posting these resources Spongeboy - I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I found the Ektron Developers Guide by Wrox to be very clear and informative
[Amazon.com Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470885696)